# avoid FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version

Tags: python, pandas

```
import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plcName = "Kamppi, Helsinki, Finland"
graph = ox.graph_from_place(plcName)
```

When I run this code I get the error
FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
gdf = gdf.append(_geocode_query_to_gdf(q, wr, by_osmid))

However I don't know where the append method is being called and where to replace it with concat or how to fix this error.

Comment: There's nothing to do for you here, just wait that your library is updated. Maybe ensure that the change in planned in your library's tracker?

Comment: It's not your fault. Try to update `osmnx` https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/pull/800  IMO `warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=FutureWarning)` may be used as a workaround.

Comment: This warning will be resolved in the upcoming release.